# ImageButton Not clickable - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have these declarations for 4 ImageButtons on my Android app, but so far they aren't clickable, this is my class:

```
public class WelcomeScreen extends Activity {

ImageButton completeprofile;
ImageButton gotoportfolio;
ImageButton findfriends;
ImageButton readnews;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_activity);

    completeprofile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.completeprofile);
    gotoportfolio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gotoportfolio);
    findfriends = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.findfriends);
    readnews = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.readnews);

    completeprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, ProfileMember.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    gotoportfolio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, PortfolioMember.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
    });

    findfriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
    });

    readnews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, WebActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
    });

}    }
```

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/completeprofile"
            android:background="@drawable/completeprofile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/gotoportfolio"
            android:background="@drawable/gotoportfolio"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/findfriends"
            android:background="@drawable/findfriends"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/readnews"
            android:background="@drawable/readnews"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

They show perfectly, but so far I cannot click any of them, no stacktrace error, I'm quite puzzled about it =/

Anybody can shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to Build>Clean Project and retry.

Comment: Do regular buttons work?

Comment: Yes, well I didn't Clean the project since I've added'em, let me try what @GiruBhai suggests

Comment: Nothing, doesn't work yet :(

Comment: check with logct or any toast msg.....

Comment: @NeoVe I just pasted your code and changed the Intent with Toast its working fine. Can you check it if toast is showing or not

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The Activities don't start when you click the buttons? Or the Activities start but you don't see the effect of the button being clicked? Are your drawables .png files or XML drawable selectors?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, problem may be in your other activities which calls on your Imagebutton click.

Comment: @rubenlop88 I mean they doesn't do anything, like a plain image or something

Comment: Yeah It's weird, going to do a check now

Comment: I guess they are plain PNG images. You should use the `android:src` attribute instead of `android:background`. If you want to change the background you must use an XML drawable selector, see the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: Yeah @rubenlop88 it was that, now it's behaving like a button, thank you very much, it's not loading the activities but that's another story, thank you again!

Comment: I will post the comment as an answer, can you accept it?

Comment: Have you declared the activities in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Oh... I think one or two aren't declared there, lol, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using PNG images as background. You should use the `android:src` attribute instead of `android:background` to get the touch feedback when the button is being clicked. If you want to change the background you must use an XML drawable selector. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 1):

This Work fine to me.

Use This in Xml

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:onClick="AddInfo"
        android:background="@mipmap/ea_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Use This in Activity Class

```
  public void AddInfo(View view) {

///// Use Your Own code /////////

}
```